# Proof of Minkowski determinant inequality

Tags: matrices, reference-request, determinant

I wonder where can I find the proof for the Minkowski determinant inequality?

( i.e., given two positive definite n x n symmetric matricies A and B, $det(A+B)^{1/n}\ge det(A)^{1/n}+det(B)^{1/n}$ )

Thanks very much!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65424/determinant-of-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices

Comment: Thanks!  Does there exist a "generalized version" of the Minkowski determinant inequality such that matrices A and B above could be any symmetric matrices without the need of positive definiteness?  (For instance, A is positive definite, but B is negative definite)