# An inequality involving two P.D. matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, positive-definite

Let $A$ and $B$ are two positive definite (by  definition,automatically symmetric) matrices of order $n$.Now how can we show that $(det(A+B))^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq(detA)^\frac{1}{n}+(detB)^\frac{1}{n}$?

My attempt:

If $A$ and $B$ commute then we have a simultaneous diagonalization by an orthogonal matrix $P$.Then $\frac{LHS}{RHS}$ becomes a nice expression after substituting by $P$ and that diagonal matrix.Then $P$ gets cancelled and we can easily calculate those determinants since those are diagonal matrices.And the rest follows from basic Bernoulli's inequality.

Now we have to manage when $A$ and $B$ don't commute.Can anyone  suggest me something? or I would be happy to learn if there is any other method to deal with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932712/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every pair of positive definite matrices can be simultaneously diagonalised *by congruence*: let $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}=QDQ^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation. Then $A=(A^{1/2}Q)(Q^TA^{1/2})$ and $B=(A^{1/2}Q)D(Q^TA^{1/2})$. Hence
\begin{aligned}
&(\det(A+B))^{1/n}-\det(A)^{1/n}-\det(B)^{1/n}\\
=\,&\det(A^{1/2}Q)^{1/n}\left[\det(I+D)^{1/n}
-1-\det(D)^{1/n}\right]\det(Q^TA^{1/2})^{1/n}\\
=\,&\det(A)^{1/n}\left[\det(I+D)^{1/n}
-1-\det(D)^{1/n}\right]
\end{aligned}
and you may continue from here.

Comment: Hello!! I have recently learnt that,you don't need both of them to be PD,just at least one of them would suffice.

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar While you don't need both of them to be PD in order to simultaneously diagonalised by congruence, you **do** need them to be PD to guarantee that $(\det A)^{1/n}$ and $(\det B)^{1/n}$ are real numbers.

Comment: No,i mean for simultaneous diagonalization you don't both of them,i am not  talking about  my question.